# Is it possible to make full viewport width <tr> hover, when table is thinner?

Tags: html, css

I've got a table f.e. 1260px wide and I would like to make a `<tr>` hover with backgroud color change, but the color should change on full viewport width, not only in table width. Is it possible to make it via css?
What I've got so far is on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqk1qnLc/2/), but it doesn't work in Safari and makes an unwanted pixels movement when hovering table row.

This is my CSS code snippet of the buggy solution:

```
tr:not(:first-child):hover:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #97999a;
        z-index: 0;
        height: 100%;
        left: calc(-50vw + 50% ); }
```

Comment: is this closer to your desired solution? https://jsfiddle.net/sqk1qnLc/3/

Comment: nope, I want a full viewport width grey hover, not only <td>s

Comment: On Chrome when your hover over first populated row, it changes both rows is this intended?

Comment: nope, i've not tested it in chrome yet, only ff and safari, so it's another bug :D

Comment: Something like this then: https://jsfiddle.net/sqk1qnLc/4/ ?

Comment: Do you mind adding an extra element just for the hover effect?

Comment: @drip good job perfect in chrome!

Comment: @drip yes, it's what I wanted! :)

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I don't think it's i big problem, don't you?

Comment: @user3216673 please have in mind that this solution will have issues on IE. :)